# How do I make hierarchical\cascading query\report in Access?

Tags: sql, excel, database, ms-access

Let's say I have this data:

```
 Name_Middle --- Name_First --- Name_Last --- User_Data --- Status
    Joe_2           Joe_1       Joe_3         Joe_data_1       OK
    Joe_2           Joe_1       Joe_3         Joe_data_2      !!!
    Joe_2           Joe_1       Joe_3         Joe_data_1       ОК
    Sam_2           Sam_1       Sam_3         Sam_data_1       ОК
    Sam_2           Sam_1       Sam_3         Sam_data_2      !!!
    Sam_2           Sam_1       Sam_3         Sam_data_3       ОК`
```

I need to display it in such format:

```
 Name_Middle --- Name_First --- Name_Last --- User_Data --- Data_Status
    Joe_2           Joe_1       Joe_3         Joe_data_1       OK
                                              Joe_data_2      !!!
                                              Joe_data_1       ОК
    Sam_2           Sam_1       Sam_3         Sam_data_1       ОК
                                              Sam_data_2      !!!
                                              Sam_data_3       ОК`
```

I could not figure out how to group data by multiple fileds in Access report without combining it in one field (in this case I would lose the ability to sort by first/last name, for example).

And I don't like the report format, I want the data in pure datasheet view, so I could filter/sort it. Probably the Excel would be the better tool?

I would appreciate any tips, thanks!

Comment: There is no efficient way to do this in MS Access. Do it at the application layer instead.

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you elaborate a little, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used reports in *years* but isn't this ***exactly*** what you're trying to do?

You can group by more than one field in ***block format***:

[image: screenshot]

[image: example animated]

**Report Design View**
[image: layour]

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : **[Create a grouped or summary report](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-f23301a1-3e0a-4243-9002-4a23ac0fdbf3)**
- DataMagazine : [**Access: Grouped Report**](http://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/may-2016-access-grouped-report/)
- TechRepublic : [**How to group an Access report on the fly**](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-group-an-access-report-on-the-fly/)
- Quackit : [**How to Group a Report by Multiple Fields in Access 2016**](https://www.quackit.com/microsoft_access/microsoft_access_2016/howto/how_to_group_a_report_by_multiple_fields_in_access_2016.cfm)